# How to set tick label2 in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to make a plot with one set of numbers for the y axis on the left side, and a different set of numbers for the y axis on the right side. Unfortunately, when I try to set the labels myself, they don't show up in the final figure.

Here's what I've tried.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, sub = plt.subplots(1, 1)
sub.set_yticks([5, 10, 15])
for tick, lab in zip(sub.yaxis.get_major_ticks(), [1, 2, 3]):
    tick.label2On = True
    tick.set_label('')
    tick.set_label1('{:3.1f}'.format(lab*3))
    tick.set_label2('{:3.1f}'.format(lab))
    print(tick.label1.get_text(), '\txxx\t', tick.label2.get_text())
# try to force an update of the figure
fig.canvas.draw()
plt.show()
```

Output

```
3.0     xxx  1.0
6.0     xxx  2.0
9.0     xxx  3.0
```

So the text is being updated in the tick objects, but when I call `plt.show()`, I only see 5, 10, and 15 (the original values) on both sides of the axes:

[image]

I'm going to try to hack something with `twinx`, but I'd rather know how to do this properly

Comment: I would do this with a second axis, rather than labels, as in the [gallery example for temperature scales](http://matplotlib.org/examples/subplots_axes_and_figures/fahrenheit_celsius_scales.html).

Comment: I opened an [issue on github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8181) for this. Let's see if there is some solution, somewhere hidden in the code.

Comment: Good call. I managed a workaround with annotations, but that's not exactly generalizable.